# Forkjoin with empty (or not) array of observables

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I'm trying to detect when all my observables have completed. I have the following Observables:

```js
let observables:any[] = [];
if(valid){
    observables.push(new Observable((observer:any) => {
        async(()=>{
            observer.next();
            observer.complete();
        })
    }))
}
if(confirmed){
    observables.push(new Observable((observer:any) => {
        async(()=>{
            observer.next();
            observer.complete();
        })
    }))
}

Observable.forkJoin(observables).subscribe(
    data => {
        console.log('all completed');
    },
    error => {
        console.log(error);
    }
);
```

I need to do something whenever all my functions are completed. Forkjoin seems to work when the `observables` array is not empty. But when the array is empty, it never gets called. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you are missing the 3rd callback in subscribe. try this:

```js
Rx.Observable.forkJoin([]).subscribe(
    val => {
        console.log('next');
    },
    err => {
        console.log('err');
    },
    () => {
        console.log('complete')
    }
);
```

forkJoin on empty array completes immediately.

**Updated for RxJS 6:**

```
  let rep: Observable<any>[] = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < areas.length; i++) { // undetermined array length
      rep.push(this.httpService.GET('/areas/' + areas[i].name)); // example observable's being pushed to array
  }
  if (rep !== []) {
    forkJoin(rep).subscribe(({
      next: value => {
        console.log(value)
      }
    }));
  }
```

Comment: just a heads up that you probably want to check rep.length === 0 instead of comparing object references

Comment: `rep !== []` will always be false, even if `rep` is `[]`. This is because object 'values' are their reference... so let's say rep is an empty array with reference 021x7 and when you do `rep !== []` you are saying `021x7-reference !== 12039-reference` (what returns from a newly created '[]' which is what is computed from typing `[]`, analogue to doing `new Array()`), and that will always return false, because those arrays aren't the same. But this is why Geoff pointed you should instead check for length. `length` is a number, and as such, can be compared with another on the fly primitive 0

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import { forkJoin, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

export function forkJoinSafe<T = any>(array: Observable<T>[]): Observable<T[]> {
    if (!array.length) {
        return of([])
    }
    return forkJoin<T>(array);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `complete` callback. You can pass the third argument or pass an `observer` object instead of 3 arguments to make event checking more readable.

```js
yourObservable.subscribe({
  next: value => console.log(value),
  error: error => console.log(error),
  complete: () => console.log('complete'),
});
```